# Why does the background image is over written by a long text

Tags: css, internet-explorer, background-image

I have a text-field and background-image style for the field. Below is the style applied :

```
.leftPaneContent INPUT {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    background-image: url("../images/icon-search-large.png");
    background-position: 4px 3px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 1px solid #D1D1D1;
    height: 14px;
    margin: 5px 0 5px 3px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 2px 10px 4px 23px;
    width: 85%;
}
```

The image is displayed properly in FF even when I type a long value in the text-field. Whereas the image is overwritten in IE for a long value.

The problem can be seen in below image in IE

[image]

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Try using `text-indent: 23px;` instead of the padding.

Comment: This also does'nt help me as FF is disturbed with this style and screen in FF appears as in the image :(

Comment: On which version of IE do you get this error?

Comment: Is the image supposed to be a button or something? Cause else i would seperate that icon from the bar itself. Create than a table with for each (the button & the input field) a seperate field or create two divs for seperation. This way you wont have text moving over your icon, but if the image has no purpose but just for show, yea, i would stick to text-indent, since its justa single line. I am maybe more of the technical side of this, and look for a solution that may not collide with a designer. But thats me. Also, is this pure IE, or also in Chrome? Cause then its a pure IE problem.

Comment: That image has no purpose, its just background-image. I don't find this problem in FF or Chrome but only in IE 8.0.6001.18702. If at all the image had a purpose it would have been outside the text-field. Now I am thinking of the same solution instead of this UI issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

text-indent didn't fix the problem in IE. Hence I had to move the image out of text-field and wrap that inside a div :)